# sql query with out intersect operation

Tags: mysql, sql, intersection

Find all the customers from Atlantic region who have ever purchased ‘TABLES’ and the number of tables purchased (display the customer name, no_of_tables purchased)

MY sql is not accepting intersect operation

```
select c.Customer_name,count(m.Prod_id) from cust_dimen c,market_fact m,prod_dimen p where m.Cust_id=c.Cust_id and p.Prod_id=m.Prod_id and Region='ATLANTIC' group by m.prod_id
intersect
select c.Customer_name,count(m.Prod_id) from  cust_dimen c,market_fact m,prod_dimen p where m.Cust_id=c.Cust_id and p.Prod_id=m.Prod_id and p.Product_Sub_Category='TABlES' group by m.Prod_id;
```

can u modify with out intersect

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? How would you do it if you could only use 1 select statement?

Comment: but i need both the values

Comment: Hi. What does "not accepting" mean? [mcve] please. What does "i need both the values". Clarify by editing your post, not via comments. Intersect is natural join of two tables with the same columns (in order). If you need both values then you need union. A trivial google will tell you MySQL has no interesect & what to do instead. Please read & act on [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `intersect` really helps at all with this query.  I would take an approach using `group by`.  The conditions are just filtering conditions:

```
select c.Customer_name, count(m.Prod_id)
from cust_dimen c join
     market_fact m
     on m.Cust_id = c.Cust_id join
     prod_dimen p 
     on p.Prod_id = m.Prod_id 
where c.Region = 'ATLANTIC' and p.Product_Sub_Category = 'TABlES'
group by c.Customer_name;
```

A word of advice:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.